# Why this error in Three Level nested attributes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this error not display on creation of record

only come when update

[image]

please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in edit template seems to be the source of this problem.  You must have defined member's last_name without using the fields_for object.

```
<%= f.fields_for :member do |member| %>
  <%= member.text_field :first_name %>
  ... # Other attributes
  <%= member.text_field :last_name %> # make sure you are using the fields_for instance (member in this example) here.
<% end %>
```

Comment: i am doing same as above !

Comment: In your parameter hash, member_attributes includes first_name, email..., but does not include last_name, last_name seems to be in member. Check if the parameter hash is modified elsewhere, may be in controller before you're saving it. Also member seems to be outside of member_attributes, so verify that you've not defined another fields_for member with just last_name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

add attribute to attr_accessible list like

```
attr_accessible attr1, attr2
```

this is rails 3 technique to avoid unwanted attribute assignments like sensitive data from form.

Is applicable while using `object.update_attributes` function and note with `object.save`.

Comment: if attr_accesible was problem when it should display error on creation of record .. !

Comment: ArtistProfile Model connect to Profile Model ||
Profile model connect to Member model ||
Profile model connect to Website Model ||
should need to add in attr_accessible attr1, attr2  in ArtistProfile ...? i am right ?